# Best way to import excel file of 1 GB(about 600,000 records) to import to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, excel, laravel, import, amazon-rds

Currently, it is taking 8 hours to import all records to MySQL from an excel file uploaded. The excel file is about 1 GB (has about 600,000 records).

We are using bulk import, we are not looping on the records.

1. What should be done to make this faster?
2. What is the best turn around the time there can be for this import?

It's a laravel application, RDS instance, and EC2 machine (16GB memory )

Comment: `lakh' is the equivalent of 100,000, so there are about 600,000 records (see: [Lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh#:~:text=A%20lakh%20(%2Fl%C3%A6k,is%20written%20as%201%2C00%2C000.))

Comment: @Luuk Right, Replaced 6 lakh with 600,000 in the question

Comment: The question here is what takes the time in the query? 8 hours is too much for 1GB of data. Where I work it takes us about 8 hours to back up about 2 TB of data (and we are doing it pretty inefficiently as well so even that might be too much) so you might need to inspect your whole process and see where the bottlenecks are. For example `INSERT INTO ...` will be very slow because before each insert there will be a lookup on unique fields to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Save excel file data into CSV then use LOAD DATA INFILE for importing. Average time for 1Gb importing must be ~1-5 min.

Comment: How much time does it take to upload this file to the (remote) AWS site? (or are you firt putting the data on the remote site and is the 'local' import taking 8 hours?)

Comment: @Luuk: It's a local import after upload to the remote server

Comment: It is a bit difficult to tell you what you could improve in your code, if we cannot see your code. The second question is impossible to answer - depends on too many factors, including the performance of the computer doing the import, other tasks the computer is doing, mysql configuration, etc.

Comment: This package is very popular and powerfull, you should give it a try https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/ for some tips, most apply also to MySQL